# OBOUT Suite: HTML Editor - Upload Images

Tags: c#, asp.net, editor, html-editor, obout

I'm using the HTML Editor from the OBout suite which contains a lot of cool and efficient controls btw. However, I can't find a way to upload my own images from my computer to the server where i run the code using the HTML Editor. I could do this with CuteEditor with its built in upload images function.

Does anyone have any idea how to upload images through oBout Editor?

thanks

SimpleCode

Answer (score 2):

check this example in their website

https://www.obout.com/Obout.Ajax.UI/HTMLEditor/examples/Customize_ImageUploadAndInsert.aspx

I tried and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Did you define the "imageFolder" (where the images will be uploaded in the server) somewhere in your code?